# BIOS-loop after installing Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, 18.04, uefi, bios

I've recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 via Live USB but when I reboot the computer to complete the installation, this message appeared:

[image: ]]

After Clicking `OK` this other window appears:

[image]

Rebooting the computer <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Canc</kbd> and loading the BIOS, I discovered that  is actually this:

[image]

So, I can't load Ubuntu. I've tried to install Ubuntu again a number of times, with no effect. `Try Ubuntu` works fine, but I cannot do anything else.
What can I do?

Comment: What brand/model system? Just run the summary report, the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
Boot Repair -Also handles LVM, GPT, separate /boot and UEFI dual boot, only use ppa download into Ubuntu live installer.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I've an Acer Aspire E 15 E-5-575G-5385. Now I'll try to run a summary report with Boot Repair, will post the results as soon as possible.

Comment: Ok, this is the report: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/N77gWnyGzd/

Comment: With Acer you have to set "trust" on the ubuntu .efi boot file(s) from within UEFI. Many Acer also needed UEFI updates from Acer. Remember changes you made to UEFI settings as UEFI update resets to defaults. Acer Aspire E15 will not dual boot, many details Trust settings in step 35
http://askubuntu.com/questions/627416/acer-aspire-e15-will-not-dual-boot & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2297947 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2358003

Comment: YES! That worked! Plein de bonnes choses!